# Передача массива в функцию, через структуру, в которой объявлен массив

Tags: c++

Добрый день, есть функция, которая должна инициализировать элементы массива, посчитать их сумму и ср. арифметическое.
Но нужно чтоб все эти операции выполнялись для трех массивов (вводимые пользователем).

Обязательно использовать структуру.

Буду очень благодарен, если поможете ответить на вопрос: "Как можно передать в функцию необходимые параметры через структуру?"

З.Ы. Я только учусь программировать и немножко сложно дается.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

struct test {
    int m[3];
    float sred;
    int s;
};

void func_m(test a) {
    a.s = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << "Введите " << i + 1 << "-й" << " элемент массива " << endl;
        cin >> a.m[i];
        a.s = a.s + a.m[i];
    }

    a.sred = a.s / 3;

    cout << "Массив: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << a.m[i] << ' ';
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Среднее арифметическое массива равно: " << a.sred << endl;
    cout << "Сумма массива равно: " << a.s << endl;
}

void main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    test b;

    func_m(b);
}
```

Comment: Немного не понятна сама проблема, вам необходимо, чтобы функция `func_m` изменяла экземпляр вашей структуры и возращала эти изменения (тогда используйте амперсанд `&`: `void func_m(test& a)`) или что, ведь остальное у вас итак работает?

Comment: Я просто не учил еще ссылки))) 
Но все получилось)) спасибо Вам огромное))

Comment: Отлично, плохо лишь то, что вопрос остается формально без ответа :)
Либо вы сами можете написать ответ (и сумеете его засчитать лишь через 2 дня), либо я могу скопировать комментайрий в ответ, дабы не висел лишний неотвеченный вопрос.

Comment: Скопируйте и ответьте ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша проблема заключается в том, что вы в функцию `void func_m(test a)` передаете копию экземмпляра вашего класса, а не ссылку на него, для этого воспользуйтесь амперсандом (`&`) после типа переменной: `void func_m(test& a)`.